# Shopify order email template sometimes prints transaction twice

Tags: shopify, liquid

Sometimes (often, but randomly), the order confirmation prints out the payment gateway twice:

Payment
Credit card – 36.90
Credit card – 36.90

I've confirmed that real money is not being transferred twice. But could the transaction count be higher anyways? I'm not so sure about how the transaction_count works, and I don't really know how to debug this.

This part is the problem (I don't see where else it could be):

```
{% assign transaction_count = transactions | size %}
{% if transaction_count > 0 %}
  <h4>Payment</h4>
  {% for transaction in transactions %}
    {% if transaction.status == "success" or transaction.status == "pending" %}
      {% if transaction.kind == "authorization" or transaction.kind == "sale" %}
        <p>
          {{ transaction.gateway | replace: "_", " " | capitalize }} 
            —
          <strong>{{ transaction.amount | money }}</strong>
        </p>
      {% endif %}
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

I've custom built the whole shop, but I can't seem to understand why this is happening.

I'm stumped, I've reached out to Shopify support but they don't want to help because I have added some custom html in the Order Notification email.

A huge thanks for anybody that could help me with this!

Comment: It is difficult to assume with provided information. If possible, share the order transactions where it happens. Probably has something to do with transaction status.

Comment: Moreover, your mentioned approach in comment using {% for transaction in transactions limit:1 %} may not work as the first transaction may be anything like authorization etc.

Answer (score 1):

There is no other explanation than to assume that in
`transactions` there are more than one transactions. You can double check the `transaction` variable and see where the double identical transactions are coming from.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm thinking of adding a hack to only execute the loop once, no matter what. Because I'm not really sure how to debug this based only on the order notification email template made through Shopify.

I'm gonna add {% for transaction in transactions limit:1 %} in the for loop. I hope it's not too horrible of a hack.

Comment: If you loop through just one time, the significance of looping is lost. Maybe you can omit the `for` altogether? :)